# Get whole month dates based on day name

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get all dates of a month based on day name like if I want to get all FRIDAY dates from current date to a specific end date. I got a solution in SQL but can't find any solution in ORACLE.

Comment: What do you mean by "in SQL"? Oracle uses a SQL dialect. There is no pure "SQL" implementation - do you mean some other dialect, such as MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server, or what? Then: If it's "from current date to a specific end date", what does that have to do with "dates **of a month**"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hierarchy query with `next_day` function as follows:

```
-- input variable
with dataa (start_date, end_date) as
(select date '2020-11-01', date '2020-12-15' from dual)
-- your query starts from here
select next_day((level-1)*7 + (start_date - 1), 'FRIDAY')
  FROM DATAA
connect by 
   next_day((level-1)*7 + (start_date - 1),'FRIDAY') <= end_date
```

Db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38c60374c923fee26dff63a287cf5be4)

Comment: This can be simplified, by moving (level - 1) * 7 outside the call to `next_day()`. The benefit is that then `next_day()` is computed on the same input for all output rows - so it is computed only once and used everywhere.

Comment: Yes @mathguy. That can be also done and will be less expensive. Thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hierarchical query as

```
WITH t AS
(
  SELECT TRUNC(sysdate,'MM')+level-1 AS Fridays
    FROM dual
   WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate,'MM')+level-1,'Dy','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American')='Fri' 
 CONNECT BY level <= LAST_DAY(TRUNC(sysdate)) - TRUNC(sysdate,'MM') + 1
 )
 SELECT *
   FROM t
  WHERE Fridays BETWEEN :data1 AND :date2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c6d1b9b0a4443cca74dce71590e21f51)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Using connect by then filtering by Friday is a simple solution. In the example below I am using July 1st as the start date and December 1st as the end date.

```sql
SELECT DATE '2020-7-1' + LEVEL     AS friday_dates
      FROM DUAL
     WHERE TO_CHAR (DATE '2020-7-1' + LEVEL, 'DY') = 'FRI'
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= DATE '2020-12-1' - DATE '2020-7-1';
```